# Set a php object global for query optimization

Tags: php, oop, query-optimization

I have a problem in optimizing my PHP script. For example:

A MySQL Table:

```
    option_name     ||      option_value
    =====================================================
    base_url        ||      http://mysite.com/myproject
    theme_name      ||      default
    language        ||      en
```

MyScript.php file:

```
class options {
  private $options = null;
  public function get($optionName) {
    if(!isset($this->options))
        self::get_data();
    return $this->options[$optionName];
  }
  protected function get_Data() {
    // ...
    // DO A MYSQL QUERY AND SAVE IT TO $this->options
    // ...
  }
}
```

The data which this class returns is constant. So there is no need to run a MySQL query every time I need to access for example `base_url` value. **What is the best way to create an object and use it global?**

```
$OPTIONS = new options;
function load_option($optName) {
  global $OPTIONS;
  return $OPTIONS->get($optName);
}
```

Something like  this function maybe? Someone told this is **The Worst Possible Way**.

I need help. Thanks!

Comment: Did they tell you why is was the worst possible way? I usually ignore people that don't give me proper arguments, even if they are right.

Comment: `self::get_data();` doesn't this throw E_STRICT since get_data() is not static

Comment: Please, stop using global variables. Whoever told you that your approach is "worst possible way", was completely correct.

Comment: @tereško It sounds like you are such a person shouting that something is **the worst possible way** without giving good arguments and proper alternatives. I know you're right, but still you're not helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here, is that you do not understand what SOLID and DI principles are. You should implement classes that serve each singular responsibility, then inject their instances on demand.

In your case, it would look like this,

```
class Config
{
    protected $pdo;

    protected $cache;

    public function __construct($pdo)
    {
       $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function read($key)
    {
        // Read a value by its key from a table
        // Here should be a SELECT query

        // You can also prevent reading the same thing twice
        // by storing it in a cache
    }

    public function write(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

            // Here should be INSERT statement
        }
    }

    public function delete($key)
    {
         // Here comes a DELETE statement
    }
}
```

Each time you need to read a configuration value, you would simply inject an instance of `Config` to a class that needs it.

```
class Foo
{
     protected $config;

     public function __construct(Config $config)
     {
         $this->config = $config;
     }

     public function doSomethingDependingOnConfig()
     {
         if ($this->config->read('lang') === 'en') {
            // do something
         }
     }
}
```

And you would use it like,

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);

$config = new Config($pdo);

// Test
echo $config->read('lang'); //en

// So,
$foo = new Foo($config);

$foo->doSomethingDependingOnConfig();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think that's the worst possible way.

Many config settings don't need to be stored in a database. Some even can't be (like the address and credentials of the database).

So is it obvious that some hard coded config is convenient. And if you would investigate existing PHP applications, you'll see that most of them will have some globally configurable options.

The disadvantage of a global variable, is that its very strict and hard to change it's usage. Soon you'll find yourself using this global thoughout your application.

But you already countered that by wrapping access to it in a function, so you can easily change the options later, without having to change your entire application. You've hidden the way the options are stored by making this wrapper function. If you'd like, you could still fetch them from the database, or start storing them in a file, because all you need to change is this function. So this is quite a good solution, actually.

One thing you could do to improve this code:

Maybe you could wrap it in a Config singleton class. The advantage of that, is that you can actually store the config in that class as well, getting rid of the global variable, and therefor, getting rid of accidental access to that global. You will force yourself to always use the function/class access to the options.

Comment: How would a singleton be different from global variable?

Comment: @tereško The singleton class could contain the config settings in a private variable, exposing only the methods to retrieve them. That way, you can fully hide the actual config variables instead of having a global array. So that solution is similar to the current one, where there is a function to read the config, only currently one could also access the global variable itself, so that's where the advantage of a singleton class could be.

Comment: Singleton is a global variable wrapped in a class. It is just a different form of global state. Which is why is is an **extremely bad** practice.

Comment: @tereško Although I would not say 'extremely', I do agree that singletons are usually bad practice, because of the exact reason you say: a singleton is little better than a global. But there are situations in which having two instances of a class is really undesirable and for that situation a singleton is perfect. It's for a reason that singleton is a widely accepted design pattern. Not saying that you should put everything in a singleton, but for some situations it's the best solution.

Comment: @tereško In case of application config like this, it's debatable, but saying that it's **extremely bad** practise in general is jumping to conclusions too soon. But I'd like to hear your alternatives, because I'm the first to admit that in this case there will be plenty of other options.

Comment: @tereško I summed up a couple of situations where having a singleton implementation is really appropriate in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17949860/511529)

Comment: Singletons are bad because : 1) They break the SRP 2) Once you call them like, `Singleton::getInstance()` you **do introduce** another form of **global state**, which is bad.